# Register bundles from another in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'am working on a reusable bundle that will be published on Packagist.

I want make the configuration of the bundle as easy as possible.
But, the bundle uses several 3rd party bundles that involves to be registered.

Actually, this is what I need to do:

```
// app/AppKernel.php

// ...
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...
            new FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle(),
            new Gesdinet\JWTRefreshTokenBundle\GesdinetJWTRefreshTokenBundle(),
            // ...
            new RCH\JWTUserBundle\RCHJWTUserBundle(), // My bundle here
        );

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to register the set of bundles by registering only the one I've created ?

Maybe a kind of `AppKernel` that can be loaded by registering my bundle in the real `AppKernel` of the application.

If it's not possible, I would appreciate to give me the reason of why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope - it's not possible to register bundle from a bundle, best approach in this situation is clear installation documentation.

See how other open source projects deal with it. For example FOSCommentBundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md